# C# getting "DER length is '95' and cannot be more than 4 bytes" error while using SSH Ftp

Tags: c#, ssh, ftp

Code:

```
var connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo(Utilities.GetConfigValueByKey(processName + Constants.KEY_FTP_SERVER), Convert.ToInt32(Utilities.GetConfigValueByKey(processName + Constants.KEY_FTP_PORT)),
                Utilities.GetConfigValueByKey(processName + Constants.KEY_FTP_USERID),
                new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(Utilities.GetConfigValueByKey(processName + Constants.KEY_FTP_USERID)
                                               , Utilities.GetConfigValueByKey(processName + Constants.KEY_FTP_PWD)),
                new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod(Utilities.GetConfigValueByKey(processName + Constants.KEY_FTP_USERID),
                     new PrivateKeyFile(File.OpenRead(@"C:\Jobs\Test\id_rsa"), "testpwd"))
            );
```

It fails at the privateKeyfile, can someone help me what is that I am doing wrong.

I have tried the filename as a text file but still no luck.

Comment: What library are you using for PrivateKeyFile?

Comment: i am using SSH.NET library

Answer (score 5):

For the history and if could help someone. The issue for me was with the passphrase. Had an extra character (carriage return) and it makes brake the key access and show this error

Comment: For me the same, though I copied the passphrase from a web.config file to an appsettings.json and there was a & which was escaped as &amp; which I had to revert to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

I received this same error because I was using the wrong passphrase for my private key file.

```
new PrivateKeyFile(path, passphrase)
```

Additionally Renci SSH.NET wants an OpenSSH formatted key (starts with -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----). You can use PuTTYgen -> Conversions -> Export OpenSSH Key to make one.